# Extracting dict to dataframe from dataframe column containing paths

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to automate formatting a number of JSON files collected from a sensor.  I have created an initial dataframe containing the path information to each file, as well as, the labels for the sensor data.  I am trying to iterate through each JSON file, extract the sensor readings into a dataframe, and will then want to join back to the original dataframe.  Data is available at the following https://github.com/MJLongstreth/stackoverflow

This is what I have got thus far.

```
# Import necessary packages
import os
import pandas as pd
import json

data_files = []
for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for x in files:
        if x.endswith(".json"):
            data_files.append(os.path.join(dirpath, x))

# Delete variable no longer needed    
del dirpath, files, x, subdirs

# Read file paths into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data_files)

# Rename column to path
df.columns = ['path']

# Split path to extract labels, sensor type, date, filename and then join file path
df = pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('/'))['path'].to_list(),
                  columns=['delete', 'folder', 'label', 'sensor_type', 'collection_date', 'file']).join(df).drop(['delete', 'folder'], axis=1)                                                                                                       

# Initialize empty list to store data from json files                                                                                                   
data = []

# Loop over data files paths and add json file dictionary to list
for file in data_files:
    x = pd.read_json(file,
                     lines=True)
    data.append(x)

# Add data to dataframe
df['data'] = data

# Delete variable no longer needed 
del data, data_files, x, file

# Split DF into dataframes by sensor type
acc_data = df[df['sensor_type'] == 'acc']
gyro_data = df[df['sensor_type'] == 'gyro']
```

This is what I am trying to do from there, but for only one of the JSON files

```
# Unpack first level of dictionary
df_1 = acc_data['data'].iloc[0].apply(pd.Series)

temp_1 = []

for index, row in df_1.iterrows():
    temp_1.append(row.apply(pd.Series))
    
temp_2 = []

for i in temp_1:
    for index, row in i.iterrows():
        #row = row.drop('Timestamp')
        row = row.apply(pd.Series)
        temp_2.append(row)
    
temp_3 = []
    
for i in temp_2:
    y = i.stack().apply(pd.Series).mean()
    temp_3.append(y)
    
temp_4 = []

for i in temp_3:
    x = pd.DataFrame(i).transpose()
    temp_4.append(x)
    
empty_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in temp_4:
    empty_df = empty_df.append(i, ignore_index=True)
```

I started to try to combine my FOR loops, but am freezing my computer, with the following

```
test = acc_data['data'].to_list()

temp = []
temp_2 = []
temp_3 = []
temp_4 = []

for i in test:    
    for index, row in i.iterrows():
        temp.append(row.apply(pd.Series))
        for i in temp:
            for index, row in i.iterrows():
                #row = row.drop('Timestamp')
                row = row.apply(pd.Series)
                temp_2.append(row)
```

Any advice on a more efficient way to accomplish what I am trying to do would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out a solution to my problem above.  Posting the code here incase it is useful to anyone else.

```
# Import necessary packages
import os
import pandas as pd
import json
import sys
import timeit

# Start timer to evaluate script efficiency
start = timeit.default_timer()

# Initialize empty list to store json file paths
data_files = []

# Search working directory for json files and append path to data files list
for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for x in files:
        if x.endswith(".json"):
            data_files.append(os.path.join(dirpath, x))
    
# Delete variable no longer needed           
del dirpath, files, subdirs, x

# Loop to read each file in data files and extract dictionary contents to \
    # dataframe
for i in range(len(data_files)):
    
    # Each json file contains x number of dictionaries, read each dictionary \
        # into a list
    data = [json.loads(line) for line in open(data_files[i], 'r')]
    
    # Retrieve dictionary key value
    for item in data[i].keys():
        item
    
    # Retrieve dictionary data from key
    x = list(map(lambda x: x[item], data))
    
    # Retrieve dictionary key for next loop
    for item in x[0].keys():
        item
    
    # Initialize empty data frame
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    
    # Loop through extracted dictionaries and extract array information to \
        # separate lines keeping the 'Timestamp'
    for z in x:
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame(z[item])
        temp_df['Timestamp'] = z['Timestamp']
        df = df.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)
    
    # Create column in dataframe indicating the source file
    df['source'] = data_files[i]
    
    # Create file name for export from original file name, replacing JSON \
        # with csv
    file_name = data_files[i].split('/')[-1].replace('.json', '.csv')
    
    # Export each JSON file that has been converted to a dataframe as a csv
    df.to_csv('./model_data/' + file_name)
    
# End timer
stop = timeit.default_timer()

# Calculate total time
total_time = stop - start

# Output running time in a nice format.
mins, secs = divmod(total_time, 60)
hours, mins = divmod(mins, 60)

sys.stdout.write("Total running time: %d:%d:%d.\n" % (hours, mins, secs))
```